# Is there an "include" procedure in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I have some configuration in my vimrc. Some generic ones, and some other really specific.

I would like to share this config with some co workers, but a lot of them don't need these specific ones.

Instead of editing a bunch of different vimrc, I would like to know if it's possible to have an "include" directive - something like a file named ".vimrc_module" and called from vimrc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, use the `:source` command:

```
source .vimrc_module
```

See:

```
:help :source
```

for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Plugins serve this purpose.

- plain plugins are always loaded once,
- autoload plugins are loaded on demand (they are ideal to define libraries of viml functions),
- ftplugin are loaded once per buffer (when the ftplugin type matches the buffer type),
- [local vimrcs](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/) are loaded on a project-basis (non standard),
- and so on.

In other words, we hardly need to use `:source` or `:runtime` explicitly from the `.vimrc`. Yes they exist. Do we really need them? Hardly! Vim already has several idioms that take care of that.